# replacement for -description in NSObject

Tags: ios, ios8, nsobject

According to https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/description

-description method is deprecated from iOS 7.1
I wonder what is the replacement for this method please?

Comment: It is only deprecated in the `NSObject` protocol, not in the `NSObject` class. https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html

Comment: @albertamg, The description method in the NSObject class is a class method, not an instance method.  The one you are writing about returns the description for the receiving class, not instance.